AWS SES send a copy of email sent to S3
I've been trying to find ways to send a copy of email sent, including the email body and header, either sent or bounced, to AWS S3 or CloudWatch logs, but found none.
I have a website that utilizes AWS SES API to send the emails.
I've tried to explore these:

CloudTrail. Unfortunately, it doesn't record the SES SendEmail and SendRawEmail.
CloudWatch. Unfortunately, it can only log metrics, e.g. emails sent, bounced, etc.
Virtual Deliverability Manager on SES. It doesn't show the bounced emails.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any kinds of clues will be much appreciated.
